# Deduce that the quotient map $q : S_{\bullet}(X; R) \to C_{\bullet}(X; R)$ is a quasi-isomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I got the question in singular homology.
A chain map $f : C_{\bullet} \to D_{\bullet}$ is called a quasi-isomorphism if $f_∗$ induces isomorphisms in homology in each degree.
Here $C_{\bullet}\dot(X;R)$ denotes non-degenerate singular simplices and $S_{\bullet}(X;R)$ denotes singular simplices.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried? Some provocative questions: What makes singular simplices non-degenerate? Is the map $q$ obviously a chain map? On the level of homology, is it easy to show that $q_*$ is surjective? injective? If one or the other of these is difficult, what's the sticking point?

Comment: I am getting it difficult to show q* is injective and surjective...